# Migrating apollo-server-express to @apollo/server or graphql-yoga

Tags: firebase, graphql, apollo-server

`apollo-server-express` and `apollo-server-cloud-functions` are deprecated, which most tutorials online showing how to set up firebase CF with graphql rely on. I'm hoping someone can help me (and surely others), migrate things so they work with `@apollo/server` v4, or alternatively using another open source library, such as `graphql-yoga`.

To begin, here is how I had my server set up until recently:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import express from "express";
import schema from "./schema";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";
import UsersAPI from "./datasources/users";
const serviceAccount = require("../../private/serviceAccount.json");
const databaseURL = "https://my-app.firebaseio.com";

const globalServerApp = admin.initializeApp(
  { credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), databaseURL },
  "server"
);
const globalDataSources = {
  usersAPI: new UsersAPI(globalServerApp)
};

const initServer = () => {
  const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => {
      return globalDataSources;
    },
    uploads: false,
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,
    context: async ({ req }) => {
      return {
        request: req,
      };
    },
  });
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/", cors: true });
  return app;
};

export default initServer;
```

In addition, I would have this for the users schema:

```js
import { gql } from "apollo-server-express";

const UserSchema = gql`
  scalar JSONObject
  type Something {
    customer: String
  }

  extend type Query {
    doSomething(someIDs: [String]): [Something]
  }

  extend type Mutation {
    completeRegistration(
      uid: ID!
      first_name: String
      last_name: String
      invited_by: JSONObject
    ): Boolean
  }
`;

export default UserSchema;
```

How would you write these using `@apollo/server` v4, `graphql-yoga` or maybe another simple way?

Comment: Do you know that you can use `graphql` without `apollo` ? That `gql` for template strings comes from the `graphql-tag` package. You can just pass your schema strings and resolvers to `makeExecutableSchema` from `@graphql-tools/schema` package to get a full schema. From there you can create a normal `express` app with a `.post` handler where you'd forward the http request body to the `graphql` function from the `graphql` package, which returns a json response. It's a bit more typing, but it's nice to not depend on `apollo` if you don't need to.

Comment: @zoran404, thanks, that sounds great. Since I have little experience with all this, if it's not too much to ask, would you be willing to put your suggestions into code as an answer? Will the GraphQL playground still work? I think there are quite a lot of people who could benefit from a working solution without the dependency on Apollo. I know I would!

Comment: Playground is completely separate, all you need is to make a GET request handler that for it. If I get some free time I could write a short tutorial with examples.

Answer (score 1):

The primary differences between the version of `apollo-server-express` you're using and `@apollo/server` v4 are:

1. Package name changes, obviously.
2. Server implementations have been removed. This was done so that implementations could be community-owned, rather than them having to learn each new thing. Lucky for you `express` middleware is still in the main package, but now you can use the `expressMiddleware` wrapper function instead of `applyMiddleware`.
3. Playground was deprecated and removed in favor of Apollo's own "Apollo Sandbox". If you prefer GraphQL Playground, there's a plugin that needs to be installed called `@apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground`. The code below assumes you've installed that.
4. `context` became an implementation-specific function, so is no longer on the ApolloServer config. It's now on the `expressMiddleware` function.
5. DataSources are no longer in the root config. The return of the `context` function should now include `dataSources` if you want them. This should generally be a bit more straightforward.

With all of that put together (though, admittedly, without me having your code, so I can't actually test this thing running), this is what I would expect to work for you:

```js
// These are the new packages
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from '@apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground';

import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import express from 'express';
import schema from './schema';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import UsersAPI from './datasources/users';
const serviceAccount = require('../../private/serviceAccount.json');
const databaseURL = 'https://my-app.firebaseio.com';

const globalServerApp = admin.initializeApp({ credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), databaseURL }, 'server');
const globalDataSources = {
  usersAPI: new UsersAPI(globalServerApp),
};

const initServer = () => {
  const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    introspection: true,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()],
  });

  app.use(
    '/',
    expressMiddleware(server, {
      context: async ({ req }) => {
        return {
          request: req,
          dataSources: globalDataSources,
        };
      },
    }),
  );
  return app;
};

export default initServer;
```